# Java List sort remove duplicate ids and return latest DateTime

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

Have the class

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class Timestamp {
    String id;
    DateTime timestamp = new DateTime();

    public Timestamp(String id, DateTime timestamp){
         this.id = id;
         this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

And Main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Timestamp > list = new ArrayList<Timestamp >();

list .add(new Timestamp ("1"));
list .add(new Timestamp ("2"), new DateTime().plusHours(1));
list .add(new Timestamp ("3"), new DateTime().plusHours(2));
list .add(new Timestamp ("4"), new DateTime().plusHours(3));
list .add(new Timestamp ("5"), new DateTime().plusHours(4));
list .add(new Timestamp ("1"), new DateTime().plusHours(5));
list .add(new Timestamp ("2"), new DateTime().plusHours(6));
list .add(new Timestamp ("3"), new DateTime().plusHours(7));
list .add(new Timestamp ("4"), new DateTime().plusHours(8));
list .add(new Timestamp ("5"), new DateTime().plusHours(9));
list .add(new Timestamp ("6"), new DateTime().plusHours(10));
list .add(new Timestamp ("1"), new DateTime().plusHours(11));
list .add(new Timestamp ("3"), new DateTime().plusHours(12));
list .add(new Timestamp ("7"), new DateTime().plusHours(13));
list .add(new Timestamp ("2"), new DateTime().plusHours(14));
list .add(new Timestamp ("3"), new DateTime().plusHours(15));
list .add(new Timestamp ("4"), new DateTime().plusHours(16));
list .add(new Timestamp ("8"), new DateTime().plusHours(17));
list .add(new Timestamp ("9"), new DateTime().plusHours(18));
list .add(new Timestamp ("10"), new DateTime().plusHours(19));
List<Object> newList = removeDuplicates(list);
}
```

How do I remove duplicate timestamp ids from the list and return only the latest timestamp time for that id.

I tried using the following method, but already running into issues with the ids not being removed correctly.

```
public static List<Object> removeDuplicates(List<Timestamp > l) {
        // ... the list is already populated
        Set<Timestamp > s = new TreeSet<Timestamp >(new Comparator<Timestamp >() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Timestamp o1, Timestamp o2) {
                if (o1.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(o2.getId())) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });
        s.addAll(l);
        return Arrays.asList(s.toArray());
    }
```

Comment: Why not store the items in a `Set` to begin with? Also, don't convert `List<Timestamp>` to `List<Object>`.

Comment: The semantics of a `Set` are that an item is only added if not present - which differs from our requirement, that the last added timestamp with the same ID should be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you need to get the list of TimeStamp and if 2 Timestamps has same id, then you need get the latest.
Using Java 8

```
 private static List<Timestamp> removeDuplicates(List<Timestamp> list) {
        Map<String, Timestamp> collect = list
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Timestamp::getId,
                        v -> v,
                        (u, v) -> u.getTimestamp().compareTo(v.getTimestamp()) > 0 ? u : v));
       return new ArrayList<>(collect.values());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `Set` interface and then use a `Stack`

1. Set will help you to remove the duplicates. [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/set.html)
2. Stack's `pop` will help you to get the latest element added to the [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

```
// public class whatever implements Comparator<Bean>
// ...
// public void foo() {
// ...
TreeSet<Bean> ourSet = new TreeSet<Bean>(this);

public int compare(Bean o1,
          Bean o2) {
   return o1.getDateTime().compareTo(o2.getDateTime());
}
```

Now use `.first()` to get the lowest element and `.last()` to get the highest. Other methods that may be of interest are `lower()`, `higher()`, `pollFirst()`, and `pollLast()`. Hope that helps.